# IIS website not recognising local group (Windows Auth) but does recognise specific users

Tags: windows-authentication, iis-10, windows-server-2022

IIS10 Windows Server2022

I have a server (SERVER) with a local group (SERVER USERS) that was made on install of a piece of software, that includes a web interface.

In IIS, I have enabled windows authentication, Negotiate was on by default (but have also tried adding specifically Kerberos, even though it warns that "Kernel mode authentication cannot be used with Negotiable 2 providers". 
In IIS, configuration editor, system.webServer->security->authentication->windowsAuthentication: 
authPersistNonNTLM=True 
authPersistSingleRequest=False 
enabled=True 
useAppPoolCredentials=True 
useKernelMode=True 
The application pool Identities are set and interacting correctly with another remote server.

Problem: 
In IIS, for the website, under Authentication Rules: 
The install automatically added the rule - Allow| |SERVER USERS| |Local 
On other servers exactly like this one (on other jobs), I've been able to add users to that local group and it's worked without any issues. 
On this server, members of that group still can't log in (prompt just comes back, cannot log in). 
I have tried adding a new rule like - Allow| |SERVER\SERVER USERS| |Local 
but that does not work either.

If I add a rule like - Allow|SPECIFICUSER01| | |Local, it works for that user.

What could be going wrong?

-Squigz

Comment: This may work with basic authentication. It is not for Windows integrated authentication.

Comment: Open IIS log files and see what error code is there for the prompt, 401.1 or 401.3 or else.

Comment: @LexLi I've looked in a few places for log files - can you please specifically tell me where to look for the log you're referring to?
I've looked in %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles and found logs containing it loading files etc - but no access denied / granted etc. No new entries from a user successfully or unsuccessfully logging in.

Comment: @LexLi I'm now getting 401.2.5 after getting logging going.
Which is what I suspected.
Does that help you with figuring out why this might be happening?